# Import data from an Excel file to an Access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import the data from an Excel file selected by the user and importing it's data into a table in access.

To ask the user to select the file I use this code

```
Private Function importarExcelTabla()
Dim excelMedi As Variant
Dim cuadroSeleccion As Office.FileDialog

Set cuadroSeleccion = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'Abre el cuadro de seleccion de ficheros

With cuadroSeleccion
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Selecciona el archivo por favor"
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Todos los archivos", "*.*", 1


If .Show = True Then
excelMedi = cuadroSeleccion.SelectedItems(1)
```

Once is selected I use the transgerSpreadsheet to import the .xlsx file to the table from a range

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "MediPrueba", 
excelMedi, False, "A2:L950"

   End If

  End With

End Function
```

But my problem is that the table is not filled with the excel data and also I put the range from one file but:

¿It is possible to select all the document without the first line so this will work in other excel files with others lengths?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact Check out this code from www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

This code works by selecting a starting point (top right corner) and works until it encounters a blank row at which point it stops. To skip the first row set the starting point to A2

```
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean
blnEXCEL = False

' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Change True to False if you do not want the workbook to be
' visible when the code is running
xlx.Visible = True

' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
' of the EXCEL file from which you will read the data
Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open("C:\Filename.xls", , True) ' opens in read-only mode

' Replace WorksheetName with the actual name of the worksheet
' in the EXCEL file
Set xls = xlw.Worksheets("WorksheetName")

' Replace A1 with the cell reference from which the first data value
' (non-header information) is to be read
Set xlc = xls.Range("A1") ' this is the first cell that contains data

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

' Replace QueryOrTableName with the real name of the table or query
' that is to receive the data from the worksheet
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("QueryOrTableName", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

' write data to the recordset
Do While xlc.Value <> ""
      rst.AddNew
            For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                  rst.Fields(lngColumn).Value = xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value
            Next lngColumn
      rst.Update
      Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1,0)
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
Set xlc = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing
xlw.Close False
Set xlw = Nothing
If blnEXCEL = True Then xlx.Quit
Set xlx = Nothing
```